# How to check in the SheetChange event whether the change made was in a named Range

Tags: vba, excel

So I am coding in the SheetChange event in Excel. I want to know if the change was made in a named Range. So essentially:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
'Some code
If ('Target address is a part of one of the named ranges')
    'Some code here
```

Note that I have multiple Named Ranges in different Sheets which I would like to check. One way can be to loop through every named range whenever a change is made somewhere. But I don't think that's a good way to code. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    'Some code
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("MyNamedRange")) Is Nothing Then
        'Some code here
    End If
```

**EDIT:**

The above works to test if the target is part of one specific named range. If your requirement is to test whether the target is part of ANY named range, then you will indeed have to loop through the existing names - something like this would work:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    'Some code
    Dim sName As String
    sName = InAnyNamedRange(Target)
    If Not sName = "" Then
        'Some code here
        Debug.Print Target.Address & " changed, and is in named range " & sName
    End If
End Sub

Function InAnyNamedRange(ByRef rng As Range)
    Dim nm As Name
    For Each nm In ThisWorkbook.Names
        If Not Intersect(rng, Range(nm)) Is Nothing Then
            InAnyNamedRange = nm.Name
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next nm
End Function
```

Comment: Nice code! Just curious why you leave your function to return a variant instead of a string.

Comment: I was also looping through the names right now but felt that it is not really an optimal solution. Because here for every change it will check for every named range and then return. But thanks anyways. Your code is way cleaner than mine

Comment: @Brian - no real reason - I think I was initially considering returning a Boolean, then thought it MAY be useful to return the (first) matching named range name... Not sure it will make a massive performance difference either way! Tanmay - are you seeing a performance hit from this approach?

Comment: @Olly - Not much. A direct solution would have been best but, I think I can modify my current code to make it better.